# Laravel 8.24 listeners/events doesn't adds to queue

Tags: events, notifications, queue, listener, laravel-8

I want to implement email notifications for some events. Also I was this events to be processed asynchronosly using Laravel database queue.
Here is what I have:
Event class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Models\ServerReviewVote;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NewServerReviewVote
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(public ServerReviewVote $serverReviewVote)
    {
    }
}
```

Listener class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\NewServerReviewVote;
use App\Notifications\NewServerReviewVote as NewServerReviewVoteNotification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class SendNewServerReviewVoteNotification implements ShouldQueue
{
    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  NewServerReviewVote  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(NewServerReviewVote $event)
    {
        $event->serverReviewVote->serverReview->author
            ->notify(new NewServerReviewVoteNotification($event->serverReviewVote->serverReview));
    }
}
```

Notification class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use App\Models\ServerReview;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class NewServerReviewVote extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(private ServerReview $serverReview)
    {
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param User $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via(User $notifiable): array
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param User $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail(User $notifiable): MailMessage
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('New vote for your review!')
            ->greeting("Hello, {$notifiable->name}!")
            ->line("We got a new vote for your review for {$this->serverReview->server->name} server!")
            ->line("Your review currently have {$this->serverReview->votesUpCount()} upvotes and {$this->serverReview->votesDownCount()} downvotes.")
            ->line("Click the button below to navigate to the server page:")
            ->action($this->serverReview->server->name, route('servers.show', ['server' => $this->serverReview->server->slug]));
    }
}
```

I'm firing event from this observer:

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\Events\NewServerReviewVote;
use App\Models\ServerReviewVote;

class ServerReviewVoteObserver
{
    /**
     * @param ServerReviewVote $serverReviewVote
     */
    public static function created(ServerReviewVote $serverReviewVote)
    {
        event(new NewServerReviewVote($serverReviewVote));
    }
}
```

I configured queue database driver and my database has `jobs` table.
My expectations is that this event will be added to this table and than I can process it by using `php artisan queue:work`. But for some reason email sends synchronously instead of adding to queue. What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've been trying different ways and found how to make listeners to be added to queue.
I added `public $connection = 'database'` property to listener class.
Here is how it looks now:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\NewServerReviewVote;
use App\Notifications\NewServerReviewVote as NewServerReviewVoteNotification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class SendNewServerReviewVoteNotification implements ShouldQueue
{
    /**
     * Connection for queue
     * @var string
     */
    public string $connection = 'database';

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  NewServerReviewVote  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(NewServerReviewVote $event)
    {
        $event->serverReviewVote->serverReview->author
            ->notify(new NewServerReviewVoteNotification($event->serverReviewVote->serverReview));
    }
}
```

As far as I understood from Laravel docs this property isn't required but for some reason listener didn't dispatch to queue without it. Now it works good!

Also I cleared notification class as it doesn't need to implement `ShouldQueue` interface and use `Queueable` trait.
Here is how it looks now:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use App\Models\ServerReview;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class NewServerReviewVote extends Notification
{
    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(private ServerReview $serverReview)
    {
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param User $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via(User $notifiable): array
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param User $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail(User $notifiable): MailMessage
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('New vote for your review!')
            ->greeting("Hello, {$notifiable->name}!")
            ->line("We got a new vote for your review for {$this->serverReview->server->name} server!")
            ->line("Your review currently have {$this->serverReview->votesUpCount()} upvotes and {$this->serverReview->votesDownCount()} downvotes.")
            ->line("Click the button below to navigate to the server page:")
            ->action($this->serverReview->server->name, route('servers.show', ['server' => $this->serverReview->server->slug]));
    }
}
```

Now listener successfully dispatching to `jobs` table and can be processed by running `php artisan queue:work database`

Answer (score 0):

for anyone else running into a similar issue with events/listeners firing synchronously, not asynchronously as intended, but their listeners implementing `ShouldQueue`

For me, I was missing the `Dispatchable` from my event.

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;

class LogEvent
{
    use Dispatchable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class LogEventListener implements ShouldQueue
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function handle(): void
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Dispatchable & ShouldQueue =

```
Horizon started successfully.
  2023-07-25 18:32:43 App\Listeners\LogEventListener ................. RUNNING
  2023-07-25 18:32:43 App\Listeners\LogEventListener ........... 518.59ms DONE
  2023-07-25 18:33:13 App\Listeners\LogEventListener ................. RUNNING
  2023-07-25 18:33:14 App\Listeners\LogEventListener ........... 255.91ms DONE
```